# Why is the focus handler getting executed with the wrong parameter?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

I have a focus handler on a textfield:

```
$("#input").on("focus", (e) => {
    // do some stuff
});
```

When I right-click, however, I don't want that focus handler to be executed, so I did:

```
$("#input").on("mousedown", (e) => {
    if (e.button === 2) { // right click
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

However, that also prevents the textfield from ever getting focus when I right-click. I still want it to get focus, I just don't want the handler to execute, so I triggered the handler manually:

```
$("#input").on("mousedown", (e) => {
    if (e.button === 2) { // right click
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#input").trigger("focus", true);
    }
});

$("input").on("focus", (e, someParam) => {
    if (someParam) return;
    // do some stuff
});
```

This way, the textfield gets focus, but we immediately return out of the handler.

The problem I noticed is that the first time I trigger the focus handler, `someParam` is `undefined` and we end up executing `do some stuff`. For all subsequent right-clicks, `someParam` is true.

I commented out the line that triggers the focus handler, and indeed, the focus handler is never executed, because we call `preventDefault`, so it seems that the first execution of the handler necessarily comes from `$("#input").trigger("focus", true);`. So why then is `someParam` undefined if I'm passing in `true` as the extra parameter?

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bjj56eua/). Tested in Chrome.

Comment: Why are  you even calling the `trigger` method if all you do is dump out of the `focus` method? That is, you pass true when you call trigger, and if(true) you want to do nothing.

Comment: @Draco18s My intention is for the textfield to get focus. I don't want to execute the focus handler. As far as I know, the handler that an event is tied to will necessarily execute in response to the event, so the next best option is to simply return out of the handler.

Comment: Ooh, oh I see. Let me see here...

Comment: You can't be choose-y about what _triggers_ an event - but you can decide just not to do anything in your handler function, so why not do just that? Wrap whatever you want to do in the _other_ cases in `if (e.button !== 2)`, and done ...?

Comment: CBroe's the idea is the best solution I can come up with as well. The "true" only gets passed when I right click on the field, then immediately right click *again* (while the context menu is up) or if the field was already focused. Here's CBroe's solution https://jsfiddle.net/bjj56eua/3/

Comment: @CBroe There are other cases where I want `do some stuff` to execute, not just in the case that you left-click. For example, if I tab to the textfield (i.e. focus goes there), I want to execute the focus handler. I'd rather not write a bunch of code to manually trigger the focus handler in all the cases where focus would get triggered. (though maybe there aren't too many cases - mousedown, keydown->tab, ...)

Comment: @CBroe I want to trigger the focus event, so that the textfield gets focus. The "execute handler vs don't execute handler" issue is just one issue, but I still need the field to get focus.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to be a current issue with jQuery. See [this github issue](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/issues/1741).

As a workaround, try the following:

```
var a = $("#a");
var _focusData = null;

var focusEvent = (e) => {
    if (_focusData) {
        _focusData = null;
        return;
    }
    _focusData = null;
    var t = $("textarea").first();
    t.val(t.val() + "\nfocus");
};

a.on("mousedown", (e) => {
   if (e.button === 2) {
       e.preventDefault();
       var t = $("textarea").first();
       t.val(t.val() + "\n" + e.button);
       _focusData = true;
       a.trigger("focus");
   }
});

a.on("focus", focusEvent);
```

After doing a lot more research, including trying to trigger custom events with `$.Event`, it seems like your best course of action is to either use stack traces, pollute the global scope, or downgrade your jQuery version.

Comment: Good to know that this is a JQuery bug. However, this solution won't work for me, because you're simply executing the focus handler. The focus event, however, isn't getting triggered, which is what I require (I need focus to go to the text field). Second you're passing the MouseEvent to the focus handler, which should accept the FocusEvent.

Comment: 2 options: Downgrade < 3.2, or find another workaround that will work. As far as passing the mousedown event to `focusEvent`, it doesn't exactly matter as it's being returned anyway. `focus` here should still be called. I'd create a jsfiddle more closer toward your desired solution, and I can maybe assist further with a better workaround.

Comment: Yeah the Focus/Mouse event was a minor point that doesn't really matter for me. By "I'd create a jsfiddle more closer toward your desired solution," are you asking me to create another one? I don't see what other jsfiddle I can create. The one I created is my desired solution. I'll just need to come up with a workaround.

Comment: @pushkin As far as I can tell, 2 is being executed in that text field correctly, as well as focus. What should the desired result be?

Comment: I need the textfield to be focused. Notice that it doesn't have the blue outline around it.

Comment: @pushkin The only field you're capturing the focus event for is the top input. See [this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bjj56eua/5/).

Comment: Correct, I want to focus the top input, not the text area. If you run the fiddler in your answer, the input field doesn't get the blue outline when right-clicking, which is what I want.

Comment: By the way, why do you say I need to downgrade my jQuery version to < 3.2? The github issue was reported for version 1.9. Looks like I'd need to downgrade to a much earlier version.

Comment: @pushkin Yup, thought it was isolated to 3.2. Looks much deeper of an issue. Get on that ticket, and push them to fix it.

Comment: In my case, I wouldn't be polluting the global scope, because I could contain that extra variable inside of a function, so I'll mark this as the best answer. However, note that I'm marking it as the best answer, because of the new jsfiddle you added, not because of the code in your answer.

Comment: @pushkin Feel free to touch up my answer

Answer (score 2):

I found another solution besides the comment from CBroe (to just perform the logic in an `else` statement):

Use a named function as our mouse down handler, then examine the stack trace.

```
var a = $("#a");
a.on("mousedown", onMouseDown);

function onMouseDown(e) {
   if (e.button === 2) {
       e.preventDefault();
       e.stopImmediatePropagation()
       var t = $("textarea").first();
       t.val(t.val() + "\n" + e.button);
       a.trigger("focus", true);
   }
}

a.on("focus", (e, someParam) => {
    var stackTrace = getStackTrace();
    if(stackTrace.indexOf("onMouseDown") >= 0) return;

    var t = $("textarea").first();
    t.val(t.val() + "\nfocus");
    console.log(someParam);
    console.trace();
});

var getStackTrace = function() {
  var obj = {};
  if(Error.captureStackTrace) { //Chrome (IE/Edge? Didn't test)
    Error.captureStackTrace(obj, getStackTrace);
  }
  else { //Firefox
    obj = Error();
  }
  return obj.stack;
};
```

https://jsfiddle.net/bjj56eua/4/

As I was typing this up, FrankerZ posted an answer which looks *much* nicer. I suggest doing that. This was a dirty hack involving string parsing, but it *works.* It just isn't a good idea.

Comment: Won't this affect left/middle button clicks as well? (i.e. left-clicking will return out of the handler, which is not what I want).

Comment: No, as the only time `"onMouseDown"` appears in the stack trace is when we call `a.trigger("focus", true);` (due to right-clickiong).

Comment: We also don't need `someParam` any more and could call `a.focus()` directly. But it makes little difference.

Comment: I see. I didn't realize that `onMouseDown` was your named handler. Hmm, it doesn't appear to work in my case for some reason. The fiddle is mine, but when running my actual code `onMouseDown` isn't in the stack trace for the first right-click, but it is there for all subsequent right-clicks. I'll need to figure out what's different about my case.

Comment: Post your updated fiddle? (Comment here is fine) I just want to see it for myself.

Comment: I'm going to give you an upvote here. While it seems like an ugly hack, this is indeed the best way without polluting the global scope. @pushkin See my updated answer for (another) possible workaround.

Comment: @Draco18s Meant "fiddle is fine", not "fiddle is mine". I don't have an updated fiddle. I'll need to first isolate the important difference in my code.

Comment: @pushkin ah, no worries.

Comment: Couldn't figure out the difference and opted for FrankerZ's solution (the jsfiddle he linked to at the bottom of his answer). Thanks for the idea though. +1

Comment: @pushkin No worries. His answer is probably better IMO, although someone else might find mine useful. :)